# Forkjoin an array of observables

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an array of observables,

```
const resultObservable: Observable<searchObject[]> [];
let i : 0;
keywordsArray.foreach(keyword => {
    resultObservable[i] = getSearchResult(keyword); //function returns an array of observable searchObject
    i++;
});
```

now I have to concat all the resultObservable together, how can I achieve this?

Comment: `concat(...resultObservable)`. Make sure you're importing `concat` from `rxjs` and not from `rxjs/operators`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.map()` to iterate over keywords and use `concat()` to combine them:

```
const resultObservable: Observable<searchObject[]>[] = keywordsArray.map(keyword => 
    getSearchResult(keyword)
);

concat(resultObservable).subscribe(() => { /* Do Some Stuff */ })
```

Answer (score 1):

If `getSearchResult(keyword)` returns an array of objects, you can flatten the nested arrays with [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

...but it's not very rxjs.

This is one Rx way

```js
of(keywordsArray)      // observable stream from keywords
.pipe(
  concatMap(keyword => {          // convert each keyword to search results
    return getSearchResult(keyword)
  })
)
.subscribe(searchResult => ...)
```

or

```js
const searchResults$ = of(keywordsArray)      // observable stream from keywords
.pipe(
  concatMap(keyword => {          // convert each keyword to search results
    return getSearchResult(keyword)
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `flatMap()` or the alternative :

```
const resultObservable: Observable<searchObject[]> [] = keywordsArray.map(keyword => {
  return getSearchResult(keyword);
})
.reduce((x, y) => x.concat(y), []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using `forkJoin` & `of` from `RxJS`, and `Array.reduce` like the following:

```js
const resultObservable = keywordsArray.map((keyword) => {
  return of(getSearchResult(keyword)); //function returns an array of searchObject
});

// forkJoin combines the the array of observables and returns Observable<searchObject[][]>
forkJoin(resultObservable)
  .pipe(
    map((res) =>
      // Array.reduce will combine the arrays and return one array that has all the objects.
      res.reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr], [])
    )
  )
  .subscribe((res: searchObject[]) => {
    // Do here what you need with the combined result
  });
```