# rxjs - How to properly forkjoin an array of observables?

Tags: rxjs

The minimal TypeScript snippet below generates the following warning: `@deprecated — Use the version that takes an array of Observables instead`. I have looked at [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68950023/forkjoin-an-array-of-observables) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518285/how-to-combine-the-results-of-two-observable-in-angular) but I wasn't able to achieve my objective. How to properly forkJoin the observables?

```
const v0: Observable<number[]> = of([0, 1, 2]);
const v1: Observable<number[]> = of([3, 4, 5]);
const v2: Observable<number[]> = of([6, 7, 8]);
const data: Observable<number[]>[] = [v0, v1, v2];
forkJoin(data);//@deprecated — Use the version that takes an array of Observables instead
```

Comment: What version you're using? This doesn't show any deprecation notice and shouldn't https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-2m4nmj?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

Comment: @martin, thank you for the comment. I am using version 7.5.6. Since you mentioned that it worked on StackBlitz, I decided to run `npm install rxjs@latest` and it fixed it! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `forkJoin([v0, v1, v2])`. The `forkJoin(a, b, c)` it's deprecated anyway.